# MySQL wrong syntax but no line 114

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 114

but my code is only 27 lines long

```
<?php
    $DB_NAME = 'QCSYSTEM';
    $DB_HOST = 'monitor';
    $DB_USER = 'QCSYSTEM';
    $DB_PASS = '247#Direct';
    $mysqli = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    // A QUICK QUERY ON A FAKE USER TABLE
    $query = "SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

    // GOING THROUGH THE DATA
    if($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo stripslashes($row['username']);    
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'NO RESULTS';  
    }
// CLOSE CONNECTION
mysqli_close($mysqli);
?>
```

Comment: Your SQL query is wrong for starters (see WHERE without any evaluation) + ' ' around the table name which is unnecessary

Comment: It is is line `1` in SQL, but you append `14` by using `__LINE__`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to state your `WHERE` clause here

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE";
```

Either remove it

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM `users`";
```

or apply any clause

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE column = 'something'";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$query = "SELECT username FROM `users` WHERE";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);
```

You have no where clause specified so the query is failing.